# count product for different discount range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Products table with discount like

```
productid discount
1            12
2            22
3            32
4            45
5            55
6            57
7            63
8            72
9            85
```

i want sql query for product count where discount  10%-100%  or discount 20%-100% or discount  30%-100% or discount 40%-100% so on ..   discount range

My sql query is

```
SELECT Count(product_id)                     AS product_count, 
       Substring_index(value_range, '-', 1)  AS start, 
       Substring_index(value_range, '-', -1) AS END 
FROM   (SELECT product_id, 
               discount, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 80 AND 90 THEN '80-90' 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 70 AND 90 THEN '70-90' 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 60 AND 90 THEN '60-90' 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 50 AND 90 THEN '50-90' 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 40 AND 90 THEN '40-90' 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 30 AND 90 THEN '30-90' 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 20 AND 90 THEN '20-90' 
                 WHEN discount BETWEEN 10 AND 90 THEN '10-90' 
               END AS value_range 
        FROM   products) AS T2 
GROUP  BY value_range 
ORDER  BY Cast(start AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

but it not giving desire result
 expected result is

```
discount_range countproduct
10%-100%            9
20%-100%            8
30%-100%            7
40%-100%             6..   so on
```

Here is My output.

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `CASE`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: update your question adn add  the expcted  result  too

Comment: Show us sample data, current and expected output. Otherwise, how are we going to know why aren't you getting the desire result.

Comment: Great you give us desire result but still haven't shown us what is wrong with current result or what data you used to generate that result. Is like you tell us to make you a cake but didn't tell us what are the ingredients or what was wrong with the previous cake.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i added screenshot output ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need create a table for your ranges:

```
CREATE TABLE Ranges
    (`start` int, `end` int)
;

INSERT INTO Ranges
    (`start`, `end`)
VALUES
    (10, 100),
    (20, 100),
    (30, 100),
    (40, 100),
    (50, 100),
    (60, 100),
    (70, 100),
    (80, 100),
    (90, 100)
;
```

Then just found on what ranges each product discount is part of:

```
SELECT  `start`, `end`, `productid`, `discount`
FROM ranges
LEFT JOIN  products
  ON products.discount between `start` and `end`
```

Then just count it:

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42ac19/4)**

```
SELECT `start`, `end`, COUNT(`productid`)
FROM (
      SELECT  `start`, `end`, `productid`, `discount`
      FROM ranges
      LEFT JOIN  products
        ON products.discount between `start` and `end`
     ) t
GROUP BY `start`, `end`  
ORDER BY `start`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| start | end | COUNT(`productid`) |
|-------|-----|--------------------|
|    10 | 100 |                  9 |
|    20 | 100 |                  8 |
|    30 | 100 |                  7 |
|    40 | 100 |                  6 |
|    50 | 100 |                  5 |
|    60 | 100 |                  3 |
|    70 | 100 |                  2 |
|    80 | 100 |                  1 |
|    90 | 100 |                  0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a query that counts the products inside the query that groups by range:

```
select 
  concat(t.floorvalue, '%-90%') discount_range,
  t.countproduct
from (  
  select
    floor(p.discount / 10) * 10 floorvalue,
    (select count(*) from products where discount >= floorvalue) countproduct
  from products p 
  group by floorvalue
) t 
order by discount_range
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYj8tdRRnq4Eqmg69JUmKN/3).
Results:

```
| discount_range | countproduct |
| -------------- | ------------ |
| 10%-90%        | 9            |
| 20%-90%        | 8            |
| 30%-90%        | 7            |
| 40%-90%        | 6            |
| 50%-90%        | 5            |
| 60%-90%        | 3            |
| 70%-90%        | 2            |
| 80%-90%        | 1            |
```

Comment: Very cleaver solution. But doesn't return empty ranges.

Comment: No t doesn't. This would need a new table like the one in your answer.

Comment: in my table data it skipping 30%-100% value

Comment: anyway i will try @JuanCarlosOropeza method

Comment: This is because you don't have discounts in all ranges. If you want all the ranges try with a new table like in the answer of @JuanCarlosOropeza.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select
    x.bin,
    x.bin_count,
    sum(y.bin_count) as cumulative_count
from
    (   select
            floor(discount / 10) as lower_bound,
            concat('[', floor(discount / 10) * 10, ' - ', floor(discount / 10) * 10 + 10, ')') as bin,
            count(*) as bin_count
        from
            t1
        group by
            1, 2) as x
    join (  select
                floor(discount / 10) as lower_bound,
                concat('[', floor(discount / 10) * 10, ' - ', floor(discount / 10) * 10 + 10, ')') as bin,
                count(*) as bin_count
            from
                t1
            group by
                1, 2) as y on x.lower_bound >= y.lower_bound
group by
    1, 2
```

one more

```
select
    x.bin,
    x.bin_count,
    concat('[', min(y.lower_bound), ' - ', max(y.upper_bound), ')') as cumulative_bin,
    sum(y.bin_count) as cumulative_count
from
    (   select
            floor(discount / 10) * 10 as lower_bound,
            floor(discount / 10) * 10 + 10 as upper_bound,
            concat('[', floor(discount / 10) * 10, ' - ', floor(discount / 10) * 10 + 10, ')') as bin,
            count(*) as bin_count
        from
            t1
        group by
            1, 2, 3) as x
    join (  select
                floor(discount / 10) * 10 as lower_bound,
                floor(discount / 10) * 10 + 10 as upper_bound,
                concat('[', floor(discount / 10) * 10, ' - ', floor(discount / 10) * 10 + 10, ')') as bin,
                count(*) as bin_count
            from
                t1
            group by
                1, 2, 3) as y on x.lower_bound >= y.lower_bound-- order by 1, 5
where
    x.lower_bound >= 10
    and y.lower_bound >= 10
group by
    x.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a second table, try building off of this:

```
select "10%-100%" as discount_range, (select count(*) from products where discount between 10 and 100) as product_count
union
select "20%-100%" as discount_range, (select count(*) from products where discount between 20 and 100) as product_count
union
select "30%-100%" as discount_range, (select count(*) from products where discount between 30 and 100) as product_count
union
select "40%-100%" as discount_range, (select count(*) from products where discount between 40 and 100) as product_count
```